# Change HTML element by ID

Tags: javascript, html, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change an element's CSS class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript)

Found lot of topics about this topic, but none helped me. I have:

```
<div id="text-6" class="block col-228">
```

Javascript code should add new class fit, so result should be:

```
<div id="text-6" class="block col-228 fit">
```

How to do that with javascript?

Comment: For future searching, [here's how I found that](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+add+class+to+element).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("text-6");
elem.setAttribute("class", elem.getAttribute("class")+" fit");
```

**Important note:** You need to be assure,that your `DOM Hierarchy` is constructed completely,then try to manipulate `DOM Element`s. That is why you need to put `DOM` manipulation scripts inside of the `window.onload` callback, or if you use `jQuery`, then inside of `$(document).ready` callback.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
var elem = document.getElementById("text-6");
elem.setAttribute("class", elem.getAttribute("class")+" fit");
</script>`
added in header - dont work
then tried near of this div tag, nothing too

Comment: @elwins - Seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/f3YCG/

Comment: @RobHruska I have added related note about elwins comment

Comment: hmm, then how to correctly add it to web?

Comment: @elwins Try like this:   `window.onload=function(){ var elem = document.getElementById("text-6"); elem.setAttribute("class", elem.getAttribute("class")+" fit");   };`.

Answer (score 2):

You put the following between your script tags.

```
document.getElementById('text-6').className += " fit";
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using [jQuery](http://jquery.com).  Then you can just do something like this:

```
$("#text-6").addClass("fit");
```

EDIT:

Including the whole jQuery library may be overkill for your situation, but if you're dealing with DOM manipulation a lot, jQuery can simplify things quite a bit.  If it's just for this one thing, then some of the other answers provided would be better.

Comment: Can't say I advocate including the entire source of jQuery just to add one classname to one element. Seems a little overkill...

Comment: @danwellman I've edited my answer - I was assuming that multiple manipulations were going to be done, and that the question was just about how to get it done.